# Using java how to find out an application is not used for sometime?

Tags: java, windows, desktop

Using java how to find out an application is not used for sometime?

I am having some third party application for example we can take 'Skype'. If there is no action (mouse/keyboard input)is given to skype for 5min, then my code through some popup to user. So how to check whether the application is getting input from user? I gone through internet i found the below code which is giving output if the entire desktop is idle. but i need for specific application like skype. do how to do that?

```html
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

/**
* Utility method to retrieve the idle time on Windows and sample code to test it.
* JNA shall be present in your classpath for this to work (and compile).
* @author ochafik
*/
public class Win32IdleTime {

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);

/**
* Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.
* @see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx
* @return number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.
*/
public int GetTickCount();
};

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
User32 INSTANCE = (User32)Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

/**
* Contains the time of the last input.
* @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/userinput/keyboardinput/keyboardinputreference/keyboardinputstructures/lastinputinfo.asp
*/
public static class LASTINPUTINFO extends Structure {
public int cbSize = 8;

/// Tick count of when the last input event was received.
public int dwTime;
}

/**
* Retrieves the time of the last input event.
* @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/userinput/keyboardinput/keyboardinputreference/keyboardinputfunctions/getlastinputinfo.asp
* @return time of the last input event, in milliseconds
*/
public boolean GetLastInputInfo(LASTINPUTINFO result);
};

/**
* Get the amount of milliseconds that have elapsed since the last input event
* (mouse or keyboard)
* @return idle time in milliseconds
*/
public static int getIdleTimeMillisWin32() {
User32.LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new User32.LASTINPUTINFO();
User32.INSTANCE.GetLastInputInfo(lastInputInfo);
return Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime;
}

enum State {
UNKNOWN, ONLINE, IDLE, AWAY
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
if (!System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
System.err.println("ERROR: Only implemented on Windows");
System.exit(1);
}
State state = State.UNKNOWN;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

for (;;) {
int idleSec = getIdleTimeMillisWin32() / 1000;

State newState =
idleSec < 30 ? State.ONLINE :
idleSec > 5 * 60 ? State.AWAY : State.IDLE;

if (newState != state) {
state = newState;
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()) + " # " + state);
}
try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not used"? Not receiving keyboard or mouse input? Not having threads doing work in background? You have to be more specific.

Comment: This sounds like a very platform-specific feature that you are looking for, and Java only supports features that can be implemented cross-platform. If this feature is possible on Windows, then you probably need to write a native-interface wrapper around it or invoke some external command.

Comment: You can simply save a date somewhere whenever your application does something. After that you simply have to subtract the current date with the last usage date.

Comment: Please undo the edit and open a new question with edited text, cause otherwise the answer don't fit and later nobody knows the topic of that question.

Answer (score 2):

I think with not used you mean, that you as the user don't use it active. Than you can use a WindowListener. Here is an example working code(hope that's what you wanted):

```
public class AwayTimer {
    private JFrame mainframe;  // the mainframe in which everything will we
    private JLabel timeLabel;  // our label which stores the time when were leaving the window

    private long leaveTime = 0; // that time is set to zero, to prevent it later saying strange numbers

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AwayTimer(); // create new AwayTimer object
    }

    public AwayTimer() {
        mainframe = new JFrame("Away Timer"); // create new Frame with name Away Timer

        timeLabel = new JLabel ("You were 0 seconds away.", SwingConstants.CENTER); // create new label which shows the time we were away

        WindowListener listener = new WindowListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { // called on leaving focus
                leaveTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // get the time when leaving the window and save it leaveTime
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { // called on switching to Frame
                // That also gets activated when we open the program. It shows you were <ahugenumber> seconds away. To set it 0, we check if leaveTime is 0 as we initialized it
                if (leaveTime == 0) return; // we dont need to calculate anything and leave the text as it is
                long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - leaveTime) / 1000; // calculate the difference between the leave time and now and divide it by 1000 to get the time in seconds
                timeLabel.setText("You were " + difference + " seconds away."); // change the displayed text
            }

            // Other listeners, which arent important for that
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {/* do something here*/}

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {/* do something here*/}

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {/* do something here*/}

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {/* do something here*/}

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {/* do something here*/}
        };

        mainframe.addWindowListener(listener); // add the previously created listener to the window

        // add the label to the frame
        mainframe.add(timeLabel);
        mainframe.pack(); // resize the frame, so it fits the contents
        mainframe.setVisible(true);     // make it visible
    }
}
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement MouseListner and KeyListener in your application and then you can check it. But If your application is processing something that also we need to think. Please explain what your application does?

Comment: @Frozn, Perfect answer! No need to implement MouseListener and KeyListener. Super Like!

Comment: But yours is also a way to do it.

Comment: @Frozn, Yeah, but your way is easier and straight forward, I liked it!